# most active date

Tags: sql

I want to calculate what date has the most trades from the `taxi` table in 2015.

I thought of using `count(*)` to calculate the rows, then grouping it by `date`. I have  output. I am not sure I did it right or if there is a better way.

```sql
SELECT count(*), MONTH(tpep_pickup_datetime)||'-'||DAYOFMONTH(tpep_pickup_datetime) AS dates, 
AVG(trip_distance) AS avg_distance,
AVG(total_amount) AS avg_amount
FROM taxi 
GROUP BY MONTH(tpep_pickup_datetime)||'-'||DAYOFMONTH(tpep_pickup_datetime)
ORDER BY MONTH(tpep_pickup_datetime)||'-'||DAYOFMONTH(tpep_pickup_datetime)
```

The output:

[image: the output]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's unclear what your specific issue is. Does your query run correctly? If not, what is the issue? Also: Please edit your question to contain formatted text of your output, not an image of text. This [meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/272109) lists many reasons why this is important. And finally, please edit your tags to include the specific database engine you are using (I removed the other tags, aside from `sql`, as they weren't needed).

Answer (score 0):

here is some tips:

1. AVG is showing you the average per day , I think you meant sum , per your explainations.
2. not sure what you meant by most trade, but imagine you meant `total_amount`  you can sort descending based on that to show those first
3. you can group by just by the date , instead of month and day , to keep your query fast and simple , you can show month and day in your select still

---

```
SELECT count(*), 
MONTH(tpep_pickup_datetime)||'-'||DAYOFMONTH(tpep_pickup_datetime) AS dates, 
MAX(trip_distance) AS avg_distance,
MAX(total_amount) AS avg_amount
FROM taxi 
GROUP BY tpep_pickup_datetime
ORDER BY MAX(total_amount) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is mostly ok except the order by.
Because of the order by date it's difficult to figure out the most active dates from the result set.

It should be ordered by the count.

Also there is no need to split year and days in group by

I would like to write it like following

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) trip_count, 
    MONTH(tpep_pickup_datetime)||'-'||DAYOFMONTH(tpep_pickup_datetime) AS dates, 
    AVG(trip_distance) AS avg_distance,
    AVG(total_amount) AS avg_amount
FROM taxi 
GROUP BY tpep_pickup_datetime
ORDER BY trip_count DESC
```